# Why poly2 getting modified same as sum, when trying to add two polynomials using linked list in c++?

Tags: c++, linked-list, polynomials

I am trying to add two polynomials using LL, but got confused because i am getting the sum of polynomials right but my second polynomial i.e. poly2 in code also gets modified.
I am not able to figure out what's happening wrong.
Please look in to it and let me know

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class Node{
public:
    int coefficient;
    int exponent;
    Node *next;
}*poly1=NULL,*poly2=NULL;

//create polynomial using LL
void createPoly(Node **first){
    Node *t,*last;
    int num;
    cout<<"NO. of terms: ";
    cin>>num;
    for(int i=0; i<num; i++){
        t=new Node;
        cin>>t->coefficient>>t->exponent;
        t->next=NULL;
        if(*first==NULL)
            *first=last=t;
        else{
            last->next=t;
            last=t;
        }
    }
}

//display polynomial
void displayPoly(Node *p){
    while(p){
        cout<<p->coefficient<<"x"<<p->exponent;
        p=p->next;
        if(p)
            cout<<" + ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

//add two polynomials
void addPoly(Node *p1,Node *p2,Node **sum){
    Node *t,*last;
    while(p1&&p2){
        t=new Node;
        if(p1->exponent==p2->exponent){
            t->coefficient=p1->coefficient+p2->coefficient;
            t->exponent=p1->exponent;
            t->next=NULL;
            p1=p1->next;
            p2=p2->next;
        }else if(p1->exponent>p2->exponent){
            t=p1;
            p1=p1->next;
        }else{
            t=p2;
            p2=p2->next;
        }
        if(*sum==NULL)
            *sum=last=t;
        else{
            last->next=t;
            last=t;
        }
    }
    if(p1)
        last->next=p1;
    if(p2)
        last->next=p2;
    
}

int main()
{   cout<<"polynomial 1"<<endl;
    createPoly(&poly1);


    
    cout<<"\npolynomial 2"<<endl;
    createPoly(&poly2);

    
    Node *sum=NULL;
    addPoly(poly1,poly2,&sum);
    cout<<"poly1: ";displayPoly(poly1);
    cout<<"poly2: ";displayPoly(poly2);
    cout<<"added: ";displayPoly(sum);

    
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
polynomial 1
NO. of terms: 4
5 4
4 3
3 2
2 1

polynomial 2
NO. of terms: 6
7 5
6 4
5 3
4 2
3 1
2 0
poly1: 5x4 + 4x3 + 3x2 + 2x1
poly2: 7x5 + 11x4 + 9x3 + 7x2 + 5x1 + 2x0
added: 7x5 + 11x4 + 9x3 + 7x2 + 5x1 + 2x0
```

***poly2 and sum are same, don't know why?***

Comment: Discuss the effects of `t=p1;` with [your Rubber Duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: Why don't you use `std::list<Node>` (and remove the `next` member) instead of writing home-made linked list classes?

Comment: Just use `std::vector`, especially as you start by reading the number of elements. Also use the standard library and an `operator+`for your poly addition.